# Passing All Parent Attrs Through Custom Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives, one is well established/tested (in example dirB) and the other is a styling wrapper (dirA). I need to write a wrapper directive that will pass all it's attributes automatically to the child. Say for instance I have HTML:

```
<dir-a attr1="foo" attr2="bar" attr3...></dir-a>
```

and I basically want it to render as:

```
<dir-a>
    <div>
        <dir-b attr1="foo" attr2="bar" attr3...></dir-b>
    </div>
    <div class="another-div"></div>
</dir-a>
```

or:

```
<dir-a attr1="foo" attr2="bar" attr3...>
    <div>
        <dir-b attr1="foo" attr2="bar" attr3...></dir-b>
    </div>
    <div class="another-div"></div>
</dir-a>
```

or even just:

```
<div>
    <dir-b attr1="foo" attr2="bar" attr3...></dir-b>
</div>
<div class="another-div"></div>
```

How could I write my wrapper directive to achieve this?

I don't want to have to declare each attribute on the scope of dirA and prelink it to the child directive, though that would be acceptable for the fields I want to set default values for. I would like to do this only through the wrapper, not by editing the established directive (dirB).